# Is there container to store std::set, without much time initializing?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set

I'm wondering is there a good way to store `std::set`. Currently I'm implementing Floyd algorithm with multiple short paths support, in which I maintain a `std::set` to store multiple predecessors of each pair. It was computed and updated during the loop, just like the original one.

I've already tried `std::vector<std::vector<std::set<int> > >`, but found it cost a lot of time in resizing (as I need subscript in the loop). In testing a graph with about 3000 vertexes, the resizing seems never end.

But the built-in array seems to be incompatible with STL.

So, how to store `std::set` in a 2-d container which supports to visit one element by index, and don't cost much time initializing?

Comment: Any container is good as long as you are moving (as opposed to copying) its members.

Comment: How about `std::list` ?

Comment: *"But the built-in array seems to be incompatible with STL."* - I don't know what this is supposed to mean precisely, but built-in arrays can be safely used with standard algorithms, because pointers are iterators.

Comment: [This program](http://rextester.com/LJSNL39376), creating a 3000x3000 `vector<vector<set<int>>>`, completes in 0.24 sec. You are probably doing something very inefficient, somewhere in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Perhaps it's the resize(). The code before resize() is just defining all the functions and variables, and the code just stuck in this line given a large number of vector size like 3000.

Comment: If you'd like help with your code - show that code, don't describe it in prose. As long as no code is shown, there's nothing further to discuss.